# Regex remove underscores from a given string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I try to transform string using String replace method and regular expression. How can I remove underscores in a given string?

```js
let string = 'court_order_state'
string =  string.replace(/_([a-z])/g, (_, match) => match.toUpperCase())
console.log(string)
```

Expected result:

```
COURT ORDER STATE
```

Comment: Try splitting on `_` and map the results to uppercase and join back using a space.

Comment: Your expected result suggests that you want to **replace** the `_` with spaces, not just remove them. Please **[edit]** the question and clarify what you actually want to happen.

Comment: Why not just `string.replace(/_/g, ' ').toUpperCase()`

Comment: `string.replace('_',' ').toUpperCase()`?

Comment: What is the expected output of `court_order__state`?

Comment: `string.toUpperCase().replace('_',' ')` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you could match either and underscore or the start of the string `(?:_|^)` to also match the first word and match 1+ times a-z using a quantifier `[a-z]+`

Then append a space after each call toUpperCase.

```js
let string = 'court_order_state';
string = string.replace(/(?:_|^)([a-z]+)/g, (m, g1) => g1.toUpperCase() + " ");
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use JavaScript [`replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function, passing as input:

- `/_/g` as `searchvalue` parameter (the `g` modifier is used to perform a global match, *i.e.* find all matches rather than stopping after the first one);
- (*blank space*) as `newvalue` parameter.

```js
let string = 'court_order_state'
string = string.replace(/_/g, ' ').toUpperCase();
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = 'court_order_____state'
string =  string.replace(/_+/g, ' ').toUpperCase()
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as the below:

```js
let string = 'court_order_state'
    string = string.replace(/_/g, ' ').toUpperCase();
    console.log(string);
```

Here the 'g' represents global, whereas the '/' is surrounded by what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching the first character just after every _ and making them uppercase (from the regex that you have used), you can simply convert the entire string to uppercase, and replace the _ with space by the following:

```js
let string = 'court_order_state';
string = string.toUpperCase().replace(/_+/g, " ");
console.log(string);
```